# Merge two lists in Excel in ascending or descending order

Tags: excel, list, sorting, merge

I have two independent lists in Excel. I need to combine them into one list and have that list sorted either ascending or descending order.

For example how to merge these two lists (Named ranges `List1` and `List2` in Excel)

```
List1      List2
AA         BB
DD         EE
FF         GG
KK
```

into one list

```
AA
BB
DD
EE
FF
GG
KK
```

I managed to merge the lists but without ascending or descending sorting with the following formula:

```
=IFERROR(INDEX(List1, ROWS(AH4:$AH$4)), IFERROR(INDEX(List2, ROWS(AH4:$AH$4)-ROWS(List1)), ""))
```

and the result looking like this

[image]

**Can the sorted merged list be achieved using formulas only (no VBA)?**

Answer (score 2):

Please try:

```
=IF(ROW()<=COUNTA(A:A), INDEX(A:A,ROW()), IF(ROW()>COUNTA(A:B), "", INDEX(B:B,ROW()-COUNTA(A:A))))
```

Straight steal from [Jerry Beaucaire](https://superuser.com/a/404396/145438).

Answer (score 0):

If you make a new range of all cells from both lists, and call it BothLists, then you could use this-

=INDEX(BothLists,IF(ISODD(ROW()-ROW(List1))=TRUE,((ROW()-ROW(List1)+1)/2)+1,(ROW()-ROW(List1)+2)/2),IF(ISODD(ROW()-ROW(List1))=TRUE,1,2))

This assumes that, like your sample here, all the values in your two columns "tile" ALWAYS from lowest to highest when moving through the lists. (e.g., lowest value in A2, second lowest in B2, third lowest in A3, fourth lowest in B3, etc.)

In other words, it means that these two things are true-

(1) Within the same row, every value in the first Column is less that the value in second Column.

(2) Every value in the first Column is greater than the value in the Row directly above it, but in the second Column

If that's not true, please let know.

Reference - personal experience from a similar job I had to figure out where I work.

Answer (score 0):

You can do a [merge sort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Merge_sort) with formulas only, but any implementation I can think of is going to require extra scratch columns. The simplest implementation I've got uses 5 extra columns - you can easily cut that down to 3, or even 2, but IMO you're better off keeping the formulas simple and just hiding the extra columns.

[image: Example of a merge sort worksheet]

In this example we're merging the sorted ranges A1:A14 and C4:C14. In actuality it's the entirety of columns A and C - the formula I'm using determines the end of the range by looking for blanks, so that it's easy to add data later, instead of using an explicit range size. But you could change that if you wanted.

The output is in column E. The formula there is simple: `=IF(ISBLANK(G1),,INDIRECT(G1))` . The "if" is just to avoid errors when we run out of data, it's not strictly needed.

All the real work is done in column G:

`=IF(ISBLANK(H1),IF(ISBLANK(I1),,"C"&K1),IF(ISBLANK(I1),"A"&J1,IF(H1<=I1,"A"&J1,"C"&K1)))`

Most of that is bounds checking for if we run out of data in one or both of the lists. The comparison comes at the end of the expression: Construct the cell index of the item in the first list if it's <=, otherwise use the 2nd list.

Columns H and I reflect the list values based on the list indices in columns J and K. So they have simple formulas:

```
=INDIRECT("A"&J1)
=INDIRECT("C"&K1)
```

Columns J and K are also pretty simple. They get incremented based on the result of what happened in column G. The first row is static, and gets set based on where your data is. (In the simplest case, it's just 1 1.) After that, the formulas are:

```
=J1+IF(LEFT($G1)="A",1,0)
=K1+IF(LEFT($G1)="C",1,0)
```